# trigger Tooltip from JS in bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-ui-tooltip

I want to check a textarea input to see if it has at least 10 character otherwise a tooltip notification appears as info. but it does not work

I use twitter bootstrap 3

I dont want to put notification content inside HTML it should be decided by JS only.

http://jsbin.com/iVOgIxO/2/edit

HTML

```
<form onsubmit="return post_mta();">
    <textarea name="mta" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    <button type="submit">send</button>
</form>
```

JS

```
function post_mta()
{
  var ta='textarea[name="mta"]';
  if($(ta).val().length<10)
  {
    $(ta).tooltip({html:'at least 10 characters'});
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly modified version that will handle the character check:

```
function post_mta()
{
  $ta = $('textarea[name="mta"]');
  if($ta.val().length<10)
  {
    $ta.val('at least 10 characters'); /* just for testing */
    //$(this).tooltip({html:'at least 10 characters'});

    return false;
  }
}
```

However, for some reason I couldn't get the Bootstrap tooltip to render. Perhaps it may on your setup.

Comment: seems tooltip does work well only on `<a>` tags. anyway i'm thinking about using red errors rather than tooltip.